# Ограничение на вывод денег в день и в месяц

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте.
Кто может подсказать как организована логика ограничения на вывод денег или чего угодно на сайтах.
Допустим у человека на сайте есть 100 виртуальных попугаев :) нужно чтоб он не мог вывести в день больше 5, а в месяц 50.

Comment: логировать операции вывода... как разгуляется фантазия.

Comment: Два поля таблицы - попугаев за сегодня и попугаев за месяц для человека. Проверяем и логику строим при выводе/ с учетом начала месяца

Comment: либо через какое-нибудь временное хранилище с expire полем (прим: memcached) вносится запись

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно определиться в терминах. Что такое "день" и "месяц"? Если мы говорим о календарных днях и месяцах, то достаточно ввести для пользователя два поля и очищать их шедулером вначале суток/месяца.

Если же мы говорим о последних 24/24*30 часах, то тогда нужно добавить лог таблицу с полями `user_id`, `timestamp`, `quantity` и перед операцией делать запрос на проверку валидности операции, а после - фиксировать в таблице новую операцию

И конечно же и в первом, и во втором случае нужно не забывать о возможности выполнения пользователем двух операций одновременно

Comment: выполнения пользователем двух операций одновременно? как это ограничить?

Comment: @Jean-Claude транзакциями и всякими локами. В MySQL есть `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` и `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`